# how to create a custom jspdf provided in the image given below please provide code

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

i am having difficulty writing jspdf code for the image provided. i want the pdf to look exactly like the image

[image]

at first i used auto table in jspdf but that was not required but now I am having difficulty in using jspdf  without auto table and the code I have given does not display data correctly and only gives one page of data or is overlapping

Comment: Please include the best code you've managed to do, and what the result looks like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.